# Safari won't load preflight CORS auth request (XHR) in Vue.js app on Apache

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, safari, vue.js, cors

I've been researching and debugging for hours and no luck. This flow/request to work on Chrome no problem, but Safari and Firefox both die at the `OPTIONS` preflight request. Safari logs two errors:

`(!) Failed to load resource: cancelled`

and

`(!) XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://{URL_REDACTED}/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/ due to access control checks.`

I've tried a bunch of .htaccess configurations with variations on `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and I cannot get Safari past the `OPTIONS` request.

The app is a Vue.js front end using Axios to make the XHR, with a WordPress javascript web token (jwt) endpoint on the REST API that's getting called. Any help would be greatly appreciated. And if there are alternatives for the Auth process I'm open to suggestions. Using WordPress because it's easy to install and I've been a WP developer for many years.

Thanks!

**Updated :**

Here's my current .htaccess file. I've tried a number of different things though.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://{LOCAL_DEV_URL}"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you add your htaccess file? There must be some incorrect configuration in it. There are some inconsistencies between browsers in what they accept as a correct preflight response.

Comment: hey @Manduro I've updated the original post with my current .htaccess file, but I've tried dozens of variations. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A preflight request should be confirmed with a 204 No Content HTTP code (along with the headers).

Try adding the following to your `.htaccess`, right underneath the `Header` directives:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=204,L]
```

Comment: sorry @Manduro but it doesn't seem to change the result in Safari. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you show us the exact response headers returned by the preflight?

Comment: There are literally no response headers because Safari doesn't even let the request execute (or at least that's what it looks like to me). If there anything else I can provide that would help you get a better understanding?